# How do I properly install RAM (and what are timings?)

Tags: memory

I've installed some new RAM in my Asus ROG motherboard, and everything seems to be working, but I'm concerned that I haven't done it properly.

Isn't there something I need to do with the BIOS? What about timings? What are timimgs, and how do I properly install?

Comment: If you didn't install the memory the correct way you would know because your system wouldn't be working.  If the system can see the new memory then its installed the correct way.

Comment: You either would see any difference in amount of available memory or hear beep(sound) codes after turning on your machine, have you installed your memory improperly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On a modern PC, **simply sliding the RAM stick into the appropriate slot is enough.** The BIOS and OS will automatically detect and if possible (see below) use the additional memory. Some motherboards, particularly older ones, sometimes require memory to be grouped in sets of two or four identical sticks, and some will accept any configuration but run with degraded performance in an odd configuration; the manual for the motherboard will tell you if this is the case. Note that particularly if you are memory constrained, the gains from having more memory will virtually always far outweigh the slight degredation because of a lower RAM throughput.

**Timings** basically refer to the speed of the memory, and transfers to and from the memory. If you aren't overclocking your system (and if you need to ask about things like this, you probably shouldn't be), you can generally just leave everything set to *auto* or similar.

The one caveat is if you are running a 32-bit system, and are **approaching or exceeding 4 GB RAM** installed. A 32-bit OS can only (without special tricks) make use of 4 GB of address space, and some of that address space is reserved for various things, so in practice, once you go beyond either 2 or 3 GB, a 32-bit OS cannot use any more memory. In that case, you *might* see the additional memory in some kind of hardware overview or system properties, but anything that reports the amount of used and available memory won't be taking it into account because it is not usable to the OS. If you hit that limit, normally you'd want to install a 64-bit variant of the OS instead. Depending on the OS this may require a complete reinstallation from scratch or it might be possible to just replace the 32-bit OS with a 64-bit variant.